# Firebase - Test Lab - Uploading files on physical devices

Tags: android, firebase, automated-tests, firebase-test-lab

Currently, I'm running some instrumentation tests using Android Studio on physical devices. But for certain instrumentation tests certain audio files are required. My question is whether it is possible for audio files to be uploaded to the physical device storage for use in instrumentation tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can upload files before executing your test with the `gcloud` command-line interface to Firebase Test Lab. Please see the `--other-files` flag, https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/firebase/test/android/run#--other-files